# HTML + CSS dynamic render in flash?

Tags: html, apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, mxml

I have HTML + CSS text. I need some lib with simple function like "Render String Var conteining HTML" So no external files (like in flash lib called  [HTMLwraper](http://code.google.com/p/htmlwrapper/) you just have to play your SWF on top of HTML). dinamic! I give it string it renders It into some conteiner (not as a bitmab but as if it was real HTML dynamically rendered in flash). (And I need real HTML + CSS support not what normal rich text block gives us)

I am going to use it in with Flex (Flash Builder) so I like MXML component model but even pure flash AS3 will workout.

It should be Free and Opensource (any license like GPL, LGPL etc will be ok).

So Is out there such flash\flex library for HTML + CSS dynamic rendering (rfom given String or XML)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sounds like you're asking for quite a lot ;-)

The only thing that springs to mind that might be able to help is F*CSS

Take a look here: http://fcss.flashartofwar.com/

HTH

Jolyon